# what's the equivalence of "visible-xs" in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was using bootstrap 4 and watching a bootstrap 3 course and when i apply what I've watched i see noting happens so after a lot of search i realized that in bootstrap 4 there is nothing called visible-xs, visible-sm, visible-md and visible-lg as well as hidden-* so. I tried read a lot but i can't understand it really well because i'm new to css and bootstrap. what i want is the equivalence of each visible-* and hidden-* in bootstrap 4 (showing elements only on one platform)

my try:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="visible-xs">Extra Small Devices</div>
            <div class="visible-sm">Small Devices</div>
            <div class="visible-md">Medium Devices</div>
            <div class="visible-lg">Large Devices</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to BS4 alpha documentations,

> They have been replaced by .hidden-xs-up .hidden-xs-down .hidden-sm-up
>   .hidden-sm-down .hidden-md-up .hidden-md-down .hidden-lg-up
>   .hidden-lg-down.

You could read everything about migration in [BS4 Documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#responsive-utilities) directly.

Comment: That's the case in BS 4 alpha. In beta they no longer exist.